# redirect aspx to html file on local machine

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need a little help on how to redirect from webform1.aspx page to a helloworld.html page on my local machine.

I have a "helloworld.html" in my cdrive. And a.Net project has a page webform1.aspx. After clicking a button in the webform1.aspx page i have to redirect from webform1.aspx to  helloworld.html file.

Can someone provide a sample code on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you include the html file in ur project? Redirecting to a local file will only work for u, not for any other developer who will open your project. Neither will it work online for other people.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you can't access a file that is in C:/ folder of a machine, you can only access what is in the root folder of the site's directory.
`Response.Redirect` can only redirect to a url or a page present in the root directory of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use ASP.NET's [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example:

`Response.Redirect("helloworld.htm", false);`

Comment: I have already tried  Response.Redirect("C:/helloworld.html", false); and no luck. I get "This Page can't be displayed" error

Comment: You cannot redirect to a file, you'll need to redirect to an http uri (e.g. "helloworld.htm", "/helloworld.htm", "~/helloworld.htm" [relative to asp.net application], or "http://localhost/htlloworld.htm")

Answer (score 0):

You may try this....First you want to include the file `helloworld.html` in your project folder..After that you can try the following snippet..

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "onclick", "javascript:window.open( '../helloworld.html','_blank','height=600px,width=600px,scrollbars=1');", true);
```